# How to enable Intel VT-x?

Tags: virtualization, intel, bios

I have a CLEVO w150erm, with a i7-3610QM processor, which supports Intel VT-x. However in order to use it I have to activate that option in the BIOS (or so that's what I believe) but I simply can't find it.

Is there a way to let me know if I have the Intel VT-x option enabled or to activate it without using the BIOS?

If not, where am I supposed to activate it in the BIOS? I simply can't find it :S

Comment: What does your system BIOS have to do with Ubuntu? You may rephrase your question to "How do I check if I have VT-x enabled?" in case you just want to check.

Comment: no no, I know that I have VT-x. I was just wondering if there are any Ubuntu hacks that I can do to activate it, because I read somewhere in the internet that there are. Basically I am looking for help and confirmation.

Comment: *"I read somewhere in the internet"* Please be more specific and provide us a link. I would be very much interested to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to let me know if I have the Intel VT-x option enabled

Install [cpu-checker [image: Install cpu-checker]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cpu-checker), e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install cpu-checker
```

Then check if you can run KVM by using `kvm-ok`:

```
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

> or to activate it without using the BIOS?

No.

Comment: will this enable Intel VT-x ? Thanks!

Comment: No, you have to activate it in the BIOS. Every bios is a little different, on one machine I found it under the "security" section. See also http://superuser.com/questions/22915/how-do-i-enable-vt-x